# Make fancybox scale the image down rather than cropping it

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress, fancybox

I have a basic Wordpress website, where the posts are displayed on the front page. When you click a post it brings up a fancybox modal, this displays the post using the single.php template. This will just display the post thumbnail in its full size and maybe a description.

It all works apart from the fancybox which is only stretching to 600px wide. I can't find where this 600 number is coming from and as far as I can tell from the options I've given it, it should be scaling the image down to fit within the screen.

some of the options include:

```
        width     : 1000,
        height    : 600,
        minWidth  : 100,
        minHeight : 100,
        maxWidth  : 1000,
        maxHeight : 9999,
        pixelRatio: 1, // Set to 2 for retina display support

        autoSize   : true,
        autoHeight : true,
        autoWidth  : true,

        autoResize  : true,
        autoCenter  : !isTouch,
        fitToView   : true,
        aspectRatio : false,
        topRatio    : 0.5,
        leftRatio   : 0.5,

        scrolling : 'no', // 'auto', 'yes' or 'no'
        wrapCSS   : '',

        arrows     : true,
        closeBtn   : true,
```

...but I've tried seemingly every combination of these with little or no effect.

Does anyone know where this 600 is coming from or why its reverting to that size?

This is the site... http://www.marcoshype.com/

This is an example of a single post which will be in the modal http://www.marcoshype.com/photography/no-faking/

Thanks for any help in advance

Comment: fancybox doesn't crop images but auto-scale them **IF** you are targeting image file types. In your particular case, you are not opening an `image` type of content but an `iframe` (a single post) and your fancybox initialization settings have this `'width': 600` so no wonders.

Answer (score 0):

Lines 113-129 of your webpages source:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("a.fancybox").fancybox({
        'width'              :  600, 
        'height'             :  800,
        'overlayOpacity'     :  '0.4',
        'overlayColor'       :  '#000',
        'hideOnContentClick' :   false,
        'autoScale'          :   false,
        'transitionIn'       :   'elastic',
        'transitionOut'  :   'elastic',
        'type'           :   'iframe'
    });

    $(".grid_9").find("a").fancybox();

  });
```